# Onesignal OSNotificationPayload as a userInfo payload?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift4, onesignal

I need to pass a payload of type OSNotificationPayload using NotificationCenter POST request contained in the `userinfo` data but I keep getting the following error `Cannot convert value of type 'OSNotificationPayload' to expected argument type '[AnyHashable : Any]?'`

Im a swift noobie, is it possible to force this ? the affected code is below

```
        let notificationOpenedBlock: OSHandleNotificationActionBlock = { result in

           let payload: OSNotificationPayload = result!.notification.payload

            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("Notification"), object: nil, userInfo: payload )

        }
```

I have an observer setup in another class

```
    public override func load() {
       let nc = NotificationCenter.default
            nc.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.handleSignal(_:)), name: Notification.Name("Notification"), object: nil)
    }



    @objc func handleSignal(_ notification: NSNotification)
    {
        let image = notification.userInfo?["notify"] as? OSNotificationPayload
            notifyListeners(
                "myPluginEvent",
                data: ["payload":image as Any],
                retainUntilConsumed: true
            )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Notification's userInfo should be dictionary, so your code can be like following

```swift
let notificationOpenedBlock: OSHandleNotificationActionBlock = { result in

           let payload: OSNotificationPayload = result!.notification.payload

            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("Notification"), 
                object: nil, userInfo: ["payload": payload] )

        }
```

Comment: It suppresses the error alright but my notification never gets received by the subscriber, I have updated the code

Comment: @Jipsum, userInfo does not affect either posting or receiving notification, only notification name and object have influence. So, in your case the notification either not posted at all, al posted *before* you subscribe to it. By code it looks everything fine. So I would set breakpoints in *post* and *addObserver* lines to see wha't happening.